# Get results of multiple network requests when they are all done

Tags: android, async-await, future, completable-future

I'm running multiple network requests(getResponse method) in a for loop and I'm trying to get list of the responses only when ALL of the network requests are done.

I am trying to use CompletableFuture. getResponse uses OKHttp (asynch request and response)

```
Log.d("api_log", "Started doing things");

List<CompletableFuture> futures = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < mylist.size(); i++) {
    try {
        int finalI = i;
        futures.add(CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> getResponse(context, mylist.get(finalI).id)));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}

CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
                .thenRunAsync(() -> Log.d("api_log", "Ended doing things"));
```

This is the getResponse method:

```
private void getResponse(final Context context, final String id) {
    Log.d("api_log", "id is: " + id);
    final String url = context.getString(R.string.myurl) + "/" + id;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .method("GET", null)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {
            if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                return;
            }

            // response HAS RECEIVED
            final String strResponse = response.body().string();
            Log.d("api_log", "response: " + strResponse);
           
        }
    });

}
```

Actual: "Ended doing things" is printed before all the responses are printed.
Expected: "Ended doing things" should be printed after all the responses are printed.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: of course it will print `"Ended doing things"` before all your requests are done. As soon as `enqueue` method is done (without any callback methods being executed), `getResponse` is done. AS such, so is the `CompletableFuture::runAsync`. The easiest way is to make blocking calls with OKHttp; if that is an option.

Comment: I'm not familiar with OkHttp, but if the goal is to is to process requests in parallel, and OkHttp has an async mode, it seems best to rely on that and combine it with `CompletableFuture` or something similar. From a quick search I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kilink/18333e6b262189df30b9d37713f61e31) – it's Kotlin but it should be fairly easy to adapt to Java if needed.